# ZeroMQ Pattern to use for 1 to N with retry on client and connect knowledge for server

Tags: c#, zeromq

I have been reading the ZGuide about all the possible patterns available. I am trying to translate this to a C# GUI environment where the server and client need to be in separate threads to the GUI and main business rules.

I have found the lazy pirate examples very helpful, however I don't fully understanding the general pattern of ZMQ which would suit the following needs.

- Client

  - Sends messages to server with acknowledgement
  - Gets messages from server about business state
  - Has retry logic and failure logic to warn end user of server "disconnect" or "failure"
- Server

  - Receives client messages and response with acknowledgement
  - Sends extra messages based on internal state
  - Responses to retry logic on client (possibly a keep alive message)
  - Has a list of known "connected" clients based on keep alive messages being received

Currently I am confused as to what sockets I should be connecting to others. Then added to this what I have to keep in threading boundaries.

Where I am at present is the following;

|Client - Retry - REQ| -> |REP - KeepAlive - Server|

What I am seeing in my examples is that the server can't direct messages to clients that are connected. Is there a trick to storing the address of all connected clients, and allowing sending from the Server to these specific clients?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store the addresses (identities) of all known clients and send heartbeats from the server to each of those clients. Use a ROUTER in the server. Read Chapters 3 and 4 again until they make more sense.

Comment: Have re-read the guide a few times now (pre-release ebook is great too, thanks). Is there a way to use the "Smarts" ZeroMQ to remove the need to handle list of connected sockets internally? From my reading I can't see a way of doing this. If I have again missed a section, apologies.